# ip port forward iptables

Tags: iptables, routing, port-forwarding

I built a cluster of computers, they are on the LAN network behind another computer which serves as a router. I want to do a forward from external port on the router to port 22 on the submit node on the LAN network.

I am providing a simplified scheme:

```
            MACHINE 1                        MACHINE 2
            --------------------     LAN     -------------------
WAN ------ [EXTERNAL PORT       ] --------- [INTERNAL PORT       ]
            --------------------             -------------------
```

I did this procedure a couple of times before, so here is what I have done:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# For security precautions I do not provide the actual addresses and ports
export EXTERNAL_PORT=...
export INTERNAL_PORT=...
export INTERNAL_IP=...
export EXTERNAL_IP=...
export EXTERNAL_DEV=enp1s0f1
export INTERANL_DEV=enp1s0f0

export OPERATION=A

iptables -t nat -$OPERATION PREROUTING   -p tcp -m tcp   -d $EXTERNAL_IP   --dport $EXTERNAL_PORT                                 -j DNAT   --to-destination $INTERNAL_IP:$INTERNAL_PORT
iptables        -$OPERATION FORWARD      -p tcp -m state -d $INTERNAL_IP   --dport $INTERNAL_PORT --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -$OPERATION POSTROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp   -s $INTERNAL_IP   --sport $INTERNAL_PORT                                 -j SNAT   --to-source $EXTERNAL_IP
```

No error code was generated. The command **iptables -L (-t nat)** provided plausible routing tables. But for some reasons whenever I tried to connect to the submit node through routers external port **Connection refused** happens. What am I missing? The firewall is turned off.

Both machines have Debian 10. I'll provide any additional information if necessary.

**EDIT 1**

When I tried to access the internal mashine through forward, the `tcpdump` command:

```
tcpdump -lnnienp1s0f0 host $INTERNAL_IP and port $INTERNAL_PORT
```

showed no trafic, however, when I looked on the external interface:

```
tcpdump -lnnienp1s0f1 host $EXTERNAL_IP and port $EXTERNAL_PORT
```

My login atempt was seen:

```
11:15:55.776025 IP <REMOTEIPANDPORT> > <LOCAL_IPANDPORT>: Flags [S], seq 2884744900, win 29200, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3014466815 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:15:55.776218 IP <LOCAL_IPANDPORT> > <REMOTEIPANDPORT>: Flags [S.], seq 1614741316, ack 2884744901, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1837145780 ecr 3014466815,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:15:56.081390 IP <REMOTEIPANDPORT> > <LOCAL_IPANDPORT>: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 3014467119 ecr 1837145780], length 0
11:15:56.088596 IP <LOCAL_IPANDPORT> > <REMOTEIPANDPORT>: Flags [P.], seq 1:42, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 1837146093 ecr 3014467119], length 41: HTTP
11:15:56.088777 IP <REMOTEIPANDPORT> > <LOCAL_IPANDPORT>: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 42, win 227, length 0
```

I find this important because the university, where the computers are running, sometimes blocks some addresses and ports.

To be more precise, firewall is not turned off, it is not even installed.

Since **Machine 1** work also as a NAT, I am providing my NAT configuration (this, however, works fine):

```
INTERNAL=enp1s0f0
EXTERNAL=enp1s0f1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTERNAL -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTERNAL -o $EXTERNAL -j ACCEPT
```

**EDIT 2**

Command `iptables-save| sed "s/$EXTERNAL_IP/EXTIP/g"` returns:

```
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Fri Nov 29 04:50:00 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -d EXTIP/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27182 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.20.101:22
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0f1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0f1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.20.101/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j SNAT --to-source EXTIP
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 29 04:50:00 2019
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Fri Nov 29 04:50:00 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0f1 -o enp1s0f0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0f0 -o enp1s0f1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0f1 -o enp1s0f0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0f0 -o enp1s0f1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.20.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.20.101/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 29 04:50:00 2019
```

Comment: Does `tcpdump -lnnienp1s0f0 host $INTERNAL_IP and port $INTERNAL_PORT` show the traffic being forwarded to the internal host? This will identify if it's the port forward not working, or the internal host rejecting the forwarded traffic.

Comment: When you say, firewall is turned off - do you mean the firewall is OFF on the nodes where you created iptable rules ? If you created the iptable rules and turned off the firewall itself; what is the use of iptable rules ? They are supposed to be loaded in order to forward the traffic. Can you turn the firewall on and see if it solves the problem because rules you added are correct.

Comment: `tcpdump` doesn't show anything. I think the problem has to be in **Machine 1** configuration. When I tried `ssh -p $INTERNAL_PORT user@$INTERNAL_IP` from that device, everything seemed to be ok.

Comment: To be honest, firewall is not even instaled.

Comment: OK. Posting the output of `iptables-save` would be very helpful in this case.